# Find the radius of convergence of the following

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

[image]

Here I am confused on which method to use, would it be Ratio Test or Hadamards Theorem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Cauchy-Hadamard, but due to the regularity, you can also use the ratio test with the right formulation. Or you can just determine the function and find its poles.

Comment: Ok so would the limsup be infinity in this case? as every 10th term is a consecutive power of 4?

Comment: No, the $\limsup$ is finite, don't forget to take the roots.

Comment: You have posted several questions in quick succession without even *bothering* to use LaTeX

Comment: My apologies, @HagenvonEitzen I have just done a past paper, which doesn't have a mark scheme and wanted to mark it.

Comment: Even apart from my LaTeX complaint: if you post several questions in quick succession, one is forced to get the impressin that you did not spend much time with each

Comment: again @HagenvonEitzen my apologies, I had just finished the exam,and wanted to upload the questions I had trouble with.